# hide dropdown and show textbox on Cart page while selecting 10+ option from dropdown

Tags: magento-1.9, cart, addtocart

There is a drop-down value from 1 to 10+ on Cart page. Whenever I select 1 to 9 option from drop-down, Cart is updated onchange event.

When I select 10+ from the drop-down, drop-down should be hidden.and Textbox should be displayed to enter the value. Whenever I select 10+, Cart should not be updated.

```
<div class="gravdept-select gravdept-select--compact">
      <select class="qty" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getQty(); ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty(); ?>" onchange="this.form.submit()">
          <?php
               $total = 10;
                   for ($x=1; $x<$total; $x++) {?>
                         <option value="<?php echo $x?>" <?php echo ($x == $this->getQty())? "selected=selected": ""; ?>><?php echo $x?></option>
                          <?php
                             }
                             if($x == 10)
                             {
                                 echo '<option value="10+">10+</option>';
                             }
                            ?>
       </select>
```

Above code, I have written in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    showTextBox(obj) {
        if(obj.value < 9) {
            $('extra_qty_box').hide();
            this.form.submit();
        } else {
            $('extra_qty_box').show();
        }
    }
</script>    
<div class="gravdept-select gravdept-select--compact">
      <select class="qty" name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][qty]" id="cart[<?php echo $_item->getQty(); ?>][qty]" value="<?php echo $this->getQty(); ?>" onchange="showTextBox($this)" >
          <?php foreach(range(1,9) as $qty): ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $qty ?>" <?php echo ($qty == $this->getQty()) ? "selected=selected" : ""; ?>><?php echo $qty ?></option>
          <?php endforeach;?>
          <option id="extra_qty_opt" value="10">10+</option>
       </select>
       <div id="extra_qty_box" style="display: none;">
           <input type="text" class="required_entry" name="extra_qty_txt" id="extra_qty_txt" value="0" onkeyup="$('extra_qty_opt').value = this.value">
           <button name="extra_qty_btn" class="button" onclick="this.form.submit()"><span><span><span>Update</span></span></span></button>
       </div>
```

Replace your code with above code and see if it's works

Comment: I am not getting this. Kindly elaborate.

Comment: @gt06: check updated code. replace code with your existing code.